# how to handle mouse over event in legend in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am able to handle mouseover/mouseout event in donut slices .. Please check my code

http://jsfiddle.net/nyhmdtb8/6/

whenever I hover on any slice it grey out all slices expect the selected on ..can we do the same thing on mouse over of legend ?

I want to select any legend it should highlight the selected slice and grey out all ..

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter','.highcharts-legend-item',function(event) {
  console.log(event)

}).on('mouseleave','.highcharts-legend-item',function(event) {

});
```

I need to this same thing on legend mousehover

```
mouseOver: function(e) {
                 var series = this.series;
                console.log(series)
               for (var i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++) {
                var point = series.data[i];
                console.log(point)
                if (point == this) {
                    console.log('yes')
                     point.update({color: series.chart.options.colors[this.index]});
                } else {
                    point.update({
                        color: '#CCCCCC'
                    });
                }
            }

            return false;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordiong to [this post](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3166396-improve-series-highlight-on-legend-hover-event-by), you can easily do it like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    {
        // ... your params
    },
    function(chart) {
        $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie) {
            $(serie.legendItem.element).hover(function() {
                // on over
            }, function() {
                // on mouseout
           });
       });
    }
});
```

You can find a provided example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vitorbarbosa/qpByN/

You also may check the first answer of the post linked and its example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Ha3Wr/

Comment: could yo please change on my fiddle

Comment: @user944513 Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nyhmdtb8/14/ With pie type series legend items are set per point instead of per series as for other series types.