# How to set hover lineWidth when using markerGroup.toFront()?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

[Here is my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9100bo/9uk5nxea/36/)

I use toFront to change the series Z-index when the legend/series is mouseover,

but seems like the lineWidth isn't change when i write

how should i set the lineWidth attribute? Thanks!

```
element.onmouseover = function () {
           each(series, function (seriesItem) {
                    if (seriesItem === item) {
                    seriesItem.markerGroup.toFront();
                } else if (seriesItem !== item) {
                    each(['group', 'markerGroup'], function (group) {
                        seriesItem[group].attr('opacity', 0.25);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: On my device everything works fine - line while hovering has a 10 width and is on the front. Isn't it an expected output?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9100bo/9uk5nxea/41/) the series is hidden when you hover the ' Legend '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by [pistou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632067/how-to-handle-mouse-over-event-in-legend-in-highcharts)

```
function(chart){
        $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
            $(serie.legendItem.element).hover(function(){
                highlight(chart.series, serie.index, true);
            }, function(){
                highlight(chart.series, serie.index, false);
            });
        });

        function highlight(series, index, hide) {
            $(series).each(function (i, serie) {
                if(i != index) {
                    $.each(serie.data, function (k, data) {
                        if(data.series) {
                            /* data.series.graph && data.series.graph.attr("stroke", (hide ? "#D4D4D4": serie.color)); */
                            /* data.series.markerGroup && data.series.markerGroup.attr("visibility", (hide ? "hidden": "visible")); */
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    serie.group.toFront();
                    $.each(serie.data, function (k, data) {
                        if(data.series) {
                            data.series.graph && data.series.graph.attr("stroke", serie.color);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```